# ODroid XU4 GPIO pins and ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Odroid` running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and ROS Kinetic. I have `wiringPi2` installed for accessing the GPIO pins. I am able to use the GPIO pins through a Python script, but they require `sudo` access. I have a ROS node (written in Python) in which I want to access the GPIO pin data and publish to a topic. But, I am not able to do so, because `wiringPi2` required sudo access, and ROS is not defined in root.

I have tried using `wiringPiSetupSys()` function which does not require `sudo` access, but that does not work i.e. I am not able to get the GPIO pin data without `sudo` access.

All the solutions to similar problems for Raspberry Pi platform don't seem to work for Odroid.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291738/odroid-xu4-gpio-pins-and-ros/) by [akshayk07](https://answers.ros.org/users/32988/akshayk07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, I could not find a fix to the problem with the exact specifications mentioned. However, when I tested the same code on a Raspberry Pi 3 with `Raspbian`, it works correctly.

So, I have concluded that the issue lies in the OS used i.e. Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

So, a solution might be to use `Raspbian` on `Odroid` itself. I am yet to test whether that works out.

Update : `Raspbian` doesn't exist as such for `Odroid`, so some other work around might be required.

---

Originally posted by [akshayk07](https://answers.ros.org/users/32988/akshayk07/) with karma: 18 on 2018-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Re: sudo access, you can create a `gpio` group and add yourself to it:

`sudo addgroup gpio`

`sudo usermod -a -G gpio <YOUR USER>`

`vi /etc/udev/rules.d/90-gpiomem.rules`, add:

`SUBSYSTEM=="exynos-gpiomem", GROUP="gpio", MODE="0660"`
`

Got this from https://wiki.odroid.com/troubleshooting/gpiomem#rootless_gpio_accessdevgpiomem

---

Originally posted by [jdwolk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40613/jdwolk/) with karma: 21 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1